# Prove that If $f$ uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ then the left-right hand side limits exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ uniformly continuous function on $(a,b)$ then the limits
$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ and  $\lim_{x\to b^{-}}$ exists.

I read a lot of similar proofs of this kind problems, but I don't understand the intuition of these proof, and I don't have idea of how I do start.

For instance I tried to use sequence $\lbrace x_n \rbrace$ near of $a$ and $\lbrace y_n \rbrace$ near of  $b$ but I don't get connect that ideas for complete the proof, too I try use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, but I fail too.

Finally I try use the module of continuity of $f$ denoted by $w_{f}(\delta)$ and use the fact that uniform continuity implies $\lim_{\delta \to 0^{+}}w_{f}(\delta)=0$ but I failed too.

Any idea or intuition of how I should start.

Comment: You will use the fact that, the image of a Cauchy sequence by a uniformly continuous function is still Cauchy.

Comment: I should take for example a sequence $\lbrace x_n\rbrace$ such that $x_n \to a$ when $n\to \infty$ and notice that $\lbrace f(x_n)\rbrace$ is a cauchy sequence that should converges to $f(a)$ and that $f(a)=lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)=f(a)$?

Comment: $f(x_n)$ should converge but not to $ f(a)$

Comment: And  if $f(x_n)$ converges it implies that our limit $\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$ exists and apply the same argue with $b$? Or I misunderstood the idea

Comment: Look at the answer and welcome for any question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

$f $ uniformly continuous at $ (a,b) \implies$

$$(\exists \eta>0)\;:\; (\forall(x,y)\in (a,b)^2)\;$$
$$|x-y|<\eta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$
Take now two sequences $ (u_n)$ and $(v_n) $ in $(a,b)$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\to+\infty}v_n=a$$

then for $ n $ and $ m $ great enough

$$|u_n-u_m|<\eta \text{ , } |v_n-v_m|<\eta$$
and
$$|u_n-v_n|<\eta$$
thus

$$|f(u_n)-f(u_m)|<\epsilon\text{ and }$$
$$ |f(v_n)-f(v_m)|<\epsilon$$
and
$$|f(u_n)-f(v_n)|<\epsilon$$
hence
$(f(u_n)) $ and $ (f(v_n)) $ are Cauchy and converge to the same limit $ L$

By the sequential characterization of the limit, we conclude that
$$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=L$$

Comment: The first simply question is the notation $(a,b)^2$ I think that is a typo and should be $(a,b)$ only or it refers to $x,y\in(a,b)$. The second question is why $|u_n-u_m|<\eta$ and $|v_n-v_m|<\eta$ implies $|u_n-v_n|<\eta$ I don´t watch it by triangle inequality or similar argue,i think that should be $v_m$ for can say that follows that $|f(u_n)-f(v_m)|<\varepsilon$

Comment: @JuanT You can write $\forall x,y\in (a,b)$ or $\forall (x,y)\in (a,b)^2$. For your second question, i didn't say implies. $|u_n-v_n|<\eta$ because $\lim (u_n-v_n)=a-a=0$

Comment: Sorry it follow from your chose of $m$ and $n$ ? right

Comment: And finally for prove the limit in $b^{-}$ we should use the same proof that for $a^{+}$  or we should take sequences $\lbrace x_n\rbrace$ and $\lbrace y_n \rbrace$ that converges to $b$ such that $\lim_{n\to -\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to -\infty}y_n=b$ or the $+\infty$ works too?

Comment: @JuanT i said for $ n$ and $ m $ great enough $>N$. for $ b^-$ , the same method.

Comment: Thanks a lot  for give me a little bit of your time, I understand now,

Comment: @JuanT You are welcome dear Juan.